# Pass Selector Result to another Selector with Reselect

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reselect

I'm creating Selectors to get derived data from my state, but I'm running into an issue where one of my input Selectors is dependent on the result of another input Selector and I can't find a way to work around it. My Redux state is serializable and normalized similar to a relational database and the simplified version looks something like this:

```
const state = {
  tasks: {
    1: {
      manualStart: '1/1/2019'
      duration: 3
    },
    2: {
      manualStart: undefined
      duration: 2
    },
    3: {
      manualStart: undefined
      duration: 5
    },
    ...
  },
  taskPredecessors: {
    2: 1,
    3: 2,
    ...
  }
}
```

This means Task 1 must be completed before Task 2 can start and so on and so forth. I'm trying to write Selectors to derive the Start/End dates for each task based on their predecessor or use the Manual Start if one exists.

My initial instinct is to write Selectors that look like this:

```
const getTaskStart = createSelector(
  getTaskManualStart,
  getTaskPredecessorEnd,
  (manualStart, predecessorEnd) => manualStart || predecessorEnd
)

const getTaskEnd = createSelector(
  getTaskStart,
  (state, { taskID }) => state.tasks[taskID].duration,
  (taskStart, duration) => taskStart + duration
)

const getTaskManualStart = (state, { taskID }) => state.tasks[taskID].manualStart

????? const getTaskPredecessorEnd = createSelector (
  (state, { taskID }) => state.taskPredecessors[taskID],
  (predTaskID) => // Need tocall getTaskEnd of the predTaskID without ref to State
)
```

How do I create a Selector to get the Task's Predecessor End Date? I want to get the Task's Predecessor ID and then call the getTaskEnd Selector with that ID. I can't use the result of one as a parameter for another.

P.S. - I know that this is not properly memoized. I plan to use [re-reselect](https://github.com/toomuchdesign/re-reselect). Just haven't gotten to that point yet.

Comment: you just need to put `taskId` into store, and next you can easily implement what you need

Comment: Can you please elaborate more @Alex? I don't see how adding the `taskId` to the store will help anything.

Comment: I don't completely understand what exactly do you need to get. I.e. with the state you described, what should you get?

Comment: The derived state should the the start and end dates for the tasks. In the example state, Task 1 has a `manualStart` of 1/1/2019 and a `duration` of 3 (days). The Selector should calculate an end date of 1/4/2019. Then Task 2 should get the calculated start date of 1/4/2019 since its predecessor is Task 1. @Alex